Save additional fields values from WooCommerce checkout Blocks
I'm developing a Payment Gateway plugin for WooCommerce Blocks (Gutenberg). I need to get a custom checkout field in the address block.
I've managed to do so, but now I'm stuck on how I can pass the values from the frontend to the backend.
The last 3 fields are custom:

The code that generates the fields is the following:
(function () {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// Helper function to create a custom field
function createCustomField(options) {
const { formId, fieldId, labelText, validationMessage, inputName } = options;
const form = document.getElementById(formId);

            if (form && !document.getElementById(fieldId)) {
                const customFieldWrapper = document.createElement('div');
                customFieldWrapper.classList.add('wc-block-components-text-input');
                customFieldWrapper.classList.add(`wc-block-components-address-form__${fieldId}`);
    
                const label = document.createElement('label');
                label.setAttribute('for', fieldId);
                label.textContent = labelText;
    
                const input = document.createElement('input');
                input.type = 'text';
                input.id = fieldId;
                input.name = inputName; // Set the name attribute
                input.ariaLabel = labelText;
                input.required = true;
    
                input.addEventListener('focus', function () {
                    customFieldWrapper.classList.add('is-active');
                });
    
                input.addEventListener('blur', function () {
                    const fieldValue = this.value.trim();
    
                    if (!fieldValue) {
                        customFieldWrapper.classList.add('has-error');
                        customFieldWrapper.classList.remove('is-active');
    
                        let warningDiv = document.getElementById(`warning-div-${fieldId}`);
                        if (warningDiv) {
                            warningDiv.remove();
                        }
    
                        warningDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        warningDiv.classList.add("wc-block-components-validation-error");
                        warningDiv.id = `warning-div-${fieldId}`;
    
                        const warningText = document.createElement('p');
                        warningText.textContent = validationMessage;
                        warningDiv.appendChild(warningText);
    
                        customFieldWrapper.appendChild(warningDiv);
                    } else {
                        customFieldWrapper.classList.remove('has-error');
                        const warningDiv = document.getElementById(`warning-div-${fieldId}`);
                        if (warningDiv) {
                            warningDiv.remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
    
                customFieldWrapper.appendChild(label);
                customFieldWrapper.appendChild(input);
                form.appendChild(customFieldWrapper);
            }
        }
    
        const observer = new MutationObserver(function() {
            createCustomField({
                formId: 'billing',
                fieldId: 'billing-neighborhood',
                labelText: 'Bairro',
                validationMessage: 'Por favor preencha o Bairro',
                inputName: 'billing_neighborhood' // Added name attribute
            });
    
            createCustomField({
                formId: 'billing',
                fieldId: 'billing-street-number',
                labelText: 'Número',
                validationMessage: 'Por favor preencha o Número',
                inputName: 'billing_number' // Added name attribute
            });
    
            createCustomField({
                formId: 'billing',
                fieldId: 'billing-cpf',
                labelText: 'CPF',
                validationMessage: 'Por favor preencha o CPF',
                inputName: 'billing_cpf' // Added name attribute
            });
        });
    
        observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
    });

})();

I'm trying to get the fields on my main plugin file (plugin-name.php) this way but it's failing to retrieve anything...
//WooCommerce Blocks
add_action('woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_custom_checkout_fields', 10, 2);
function save_custom_checkout_fields($order) {
$logger = wc_get_logger();
$logger-\>info('Entered on woocommerce_store_api_checkout_update_order_meta', array( 'source' =\> 'aditum-pix-meta' ));
$logger-\>info(wc_print_r( $order, true ), array( 'source' =\> 'aditum-pix-meta' ));

    if (isset($_POST['billing_neighborhood'])) {
        $neighborhood = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_neighborhood']);
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_neighborhood', $neighborhood);
        $logger->info('Billing Neighborhood: ' . $neighborhood, array( 'source' => 'aditum-pix-meta' ));
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['billing_street_number'])) {
        $street_number = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_street_number']);
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_street_number', $street_number);
        $logger->info('Billing Street Number: ' . $street_number, array( 'source' => 'aditum-pix-meta' ));
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['billing_cpf'])) {
        $cpf = sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_cpf']);
        $order->update_meta_data('_billing_cpf', $cpf);
        $logger->info('Billing CPF: ' . $cpf, array( 'source' => 'aditum-pix-meta' ));
    }

}

When the log prints the $order, that's what the billing object is filled with:
[billing] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => asd
                    [last_name] => asdasd
                    [company] => 
                    [address_1] => asd
                    [address_2] => 123
                    [city] => asd
                    [state] => SP
                    [postcode] => 03530-110
                    [country] => BR
                    [email] => asd@asd.com
                    [phone] => 
                )

